# Dictionary Vs Database (Mysql)

Tags: c#, database, sockets, dictionary

This question has been asked before but not under the context of a multithreaded application.

So given a single threaded application, a dictionary will find the value given a key in O(1) time.  Given a table (from a database) which has a primary key (cluster index) on column 'X', a search for the associated tuple with a key on column 'X' will be found the tuple in O(log n) time.  Add the in-memory benefit of the dictionary, the dictionary wins hands down.

Given a highly parallel (e.g. async socket server) application that relies on a common datastructure (i.e., Dictionary vs Database) to maintain application wide state information (e.g. connected users) where say 50% of the accesses are reads and about 50% of the accesses are updates/deletes/inserts, it does not seem so obvious to me that Dictionary is better.  For the following reasons:

1) to make the dictionary thread-safe for concurrent access, a locking mechanism must be used.  lock() will lock the entire dictionary and effectively only allowing one thread to access the datastructure at a time.  Even using readerWriterLockSlim will lock the entire dictionary when elevated to writeLock.
2) Databases give the benefit of row-level locking when updating/deleting/inserting on a primary key.
3) Dictionaries are in-memory (faster) while database connection use sockets (slower)

So the question is, does the inherit row-level locking features of a relational database out weigh the benefits of in-memory Dictionary accesses?

Comment: How big is the project though? How many rows and tables are there?

Comment: At any give time about 50 concurrent users all which are sending state information at a rate of about once per second.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question, Paul. Row-level locking feature outweights benefits of in-memory dictionary access. Many additional capabilities of a relational database allows for its widespread use in comparison to an in-memory dictionary object. If you wanted to create an in-memory table for faster data access with MySQL, you could use [MEMORY storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html).

Searching for, say, just date-based information from an indexed date-based column can be rather easy and fast. Adding to that, relational databases - depending on which you use - allows for security by roles, users, business intelligence etc. On a dictionary object you would have build all the features readily available in many popular databases.

A well tuned database can serve thousands of concurrent requests that multi-threaded and disparate applications can benefit from. So before rolling out your own, I'd recommend using a relational database engine. As always, your mileage may vary based on the complexity of the problem you hope to solve.